# Laplace Transform for solve ODE (RLC circuit)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem

I have an RLC circuit and I want to know the charge on the capacitor $q(t)$ using Laplace transform:

The diferential equation is:

$$ Lq'' + Rq' + \frac{1}{C}q = E(t),$$

where

$L = 1H , R = 20 \Omega, C = 0,005 F,  q(0) = 0 e q'(0) = 0$.

$$ E(t) =\begin{cases}sin(t), & 0 \leq t  \leq  2\pi\\0, & t  \geq 2\pi. \end{cases} $$

Well, here is my attempt:

The Laplace transform of the diferential equation is:

$$\Big[ Ls^2 + Rs + \frac{1}{C}\Big]Q(s) = \mathcal{L}[E(t)] = E(s).$$

The inverse Laplace transform of $E(t)$ is:

$$E(t) = sin(t) - u_{2\pi}(t)sin(t)$$
which then gives:
 $$E(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}e^{-2\pi s}.$$

Making $ Ls^2 + Rs + \frac{1}{C}=E(s)$, we get:

$$Q(s) = \frac{1}{(s^2  + 1)(Ls^2 + Rs + \frac{1}{C})} - \frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{(s^2  + 1)(Ls^2 + Rs + \frac{1}{C})}.$$

I'm have some problem solving this Laplace inverse transform...I think I'm not solving the partial fractions well. I'm right in this point. Please how can I resolve the partial fraction and/or Inverse Laplace transform of this equation?

Comment: Are you sure that t wouldn't be greater than $2\pi$? As the conditioning on t seems to complicate your $E(s)$ value, I guess you could check again.

Comment: If you set your values of $L, R, C$, then $s^{2} + 20s + 200 = (s + 20)^{2} - 200$. Now, you can forget the exponential part for a while, and try doing normal partial fractioning.

Comment: Your last equation for $Q(s)$ looks correct, and the next step is a partial fraction decomposition. Without knowing the relative magnitudes of $L,R,C$ it is unclear what form the partial fractions will take (real fractions or an irreducible complex term) and so whether the free vibration is underdamped and oscillatory, or overdamped with exponential decay. There will be a decaying sinusoid from the pulse.

Comment: Firstly, check your $E(s)$. Anyway, if you end up with an $e^{-s}$, then you can use the [Padè Approximation][1]


  [1]: http://Pad%C3%A8%20Approximation

Comment: @sarker306 $s^2 + 20s + 200 = (s+10)^2 + 100$